# Reload data in 2nd view controller, when something is done in 1st

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am not even sure how to title this question. I will change the title as you might suggest later.
Basically, I have a sliding view controller for my side menu. Login view controller is above the sliding one. So I want data in my sliding view controller to be reloaded when login is complete and I open side view. I have tried to use delegation, but could not figure out how to set sliding view as delegate for login view controller.

What would be the best approach here. I am using ECSlidingViewController for side menu. Maybe there is a way to reload view controller using self.storyboard or something else?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you update the data when its -viewWillAppear is being called?  If the view isn't visible, does it really matter to update its contents?  I'm assuming that your slidingviewcontroller does the right thing and shows and hides its views so that viewWill/DidAppear and ...Disappear are all getting called.

If you have to update it, then I wouldn't necessarily use delegation.  If the slidingviewcontroller is a persistent object and always available, say via the rootviewcontroller, then declare a method, such as -updateData, and call it directly.

For example:

```
slidingViewController = self.rootViewController.slidingViewController;
[slidingViewController updateData];
```

Alternatively, you may have to get the rootViewController from your ApplicationDelegate or window.  Depends on where you have slidingViewController and rootViewController stashed away.

Comment: reloading data in viewWillAppear did the trick) thank you) I feel this is such a dumb question now)